# Can't access php $_POST value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, post, echo

I have this jquery function that sends the id of a div to a php file and then to a mysql table. this works fine however I can't access the value of the $_POST variable in the php file. I tried to reveal it with print_r($favid), var_dump($favid) and more but they all return something like 'array ()' or 'NULL'. it is working though because it updates in the mysql table just fine.

So my question is, why is it that the mysql table is receiving the value but it is empty when trying to access it in the php file?

I am fairly new to this, any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Jquery:

```
$("#button").click(function() {

    postid = $(this).parents('.row').attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: "favourites.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            favourite: postid
        },
        success: function(result) {
            alert('success');
        }

    });

});
```

php:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id']) AND isset($_POST['favourite'])){

$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id']); 
$favid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['favourite']);


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE user=$user AND favid=$favid");
$matches = mysql_num_rows($query);

// If it is not favourited, add as favourite

if($matches == '0'){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ajaxfavourites (user, favid) VALUES ('$user', '$favid')");
}

// Instead, if it is favourited, then remove from favourites

if($matches != '0'){
mysql_query("DELETE FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE user=$user AND favid=$favid");

}

}
```

Both of the above work, but i can't get the value of $favid like bellow...

php:

```
echo $favid;  // shows nothing    

echo var_dump($favid);  // shows 'NULL'

echo print_r($favid);  // shows '1' it should be '3'
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not use [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) to get the `postid`. `parents()` will give you all the matching ancestors `array`. This is the reason you're getting `Array()` in the server side.

Use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of `parents()`. `closest()` will give you the first matching ancestor.

```
postid = $(this).closest('.row').attr('id');
```

Comment: @jm1175 Try debugging `var_dump($_POST)`

Answer (score 2):

Can you please check that in jQuery code you got correct value for postid or not by alert or console.log

After that in php code can you please put this line before if statement and then check once.

```
$favid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['favourite']);
```

Comment: I don't think this is needed if `favourite` is `id`, it will be numeric

Comment: I checked and it is alerting the right value, its as if it gets hidden through php but then reveals itself in the mysql table. i tried putting  " $favid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['favourite']); " outside the if statement and now " var_dump($favid) " shows this:  string(0) "" ?

Answer (score 0):

Immediate parent .parent('.row');  see example https://api.jquery.com/parent/

If it is parent's parent, it will parents('unique_class_or_id'); see example https://api.jquery.com/parents/

Nearest id or class use closest() function. see example https://api.jquery.com/closest/

```
var postid = $(this).parent('.row').attr('id');
```

or

```
var postid = $(this).closest('.row').attr('id');
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation, why should use this code?

Comment: Immediate parent get with parent() function. If it is before parent in that situation parents('unique_class_or_id'). If get nearest get closest() function.

Comment: update your answer with previous comment.Your answer goes to [low quality post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8625874) where people can vote to delete your answer because you only provided code no explanation.You should include some explanation when you answer.